# Calculation of Conditional Probability Density for the Product of Two Variables given One Variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

I'm attempting to calculate the conditional probability density $f((1 + \epsilon) \cdot X | X)$, where $X$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma_1^2$, and $\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_2^2$, How to calculate this Conditional Probability Density?

Comment: This doesn't require a calculation: research "taking out what is known" for conditional probability.